# deposit into a single checking account with a joint account

Tags: bank-account, deposits

I have a check written out to me and my spouse, I need to deposit it an account that he is not on, he signed it and is out of town, will my bank let me deposit it ??

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the person who is on the check but not on the account the check is going into to properly endorse the check on the back. Some banks will accept the check as long as the other person has signed it. But to make sure it doesn't get rejected, the internal protocol for banks is to see a proper endorsing such as this.

If the check is made to Mr. X and Ms. Y and you are depositing it in Mr. X's account only. The endorsement on the back would be:

```
(Mr. X's Signature)
Pay to the order of Mr. X
(Ms. Y's Signature)
FOR DEPOSIT ONLY
```

This will be honored by all banks. If you try to cash it, you will run into problems. But if you simply deposit it, you will be fine. Hence why that last line is needed.